# The number of HTTP requests need to be made for downing a webpage?

Tags: http

Are all assets (html files, js files, css files, images) in one webpage transmitted through a single HTTP request/response, or through multiple HTTP requests/responses, one for each asset?
Assumed no XHR in that webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, each asset is a separate request. In practise, most servers allow the browser to re-use the same physical socket connection for multiple requests (but they are still issued one after the other) and this can significantly improve performance (because you need extra round-trips to establish a connection, and subsequent requests can piggy-back on the ACKs for the previous request: you cut down on a lot of round-trips).

But yes, there is always one request/response per asset on the page.

On connections with high latency (e.g. Australia -> U.S.) the number of round-trips can be a significant bottleneck, and that's why things like [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) are widely used.

Answer (score 3):

All the digital assets on a web document are transmitted on separate [HTTP requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http_request#Request_message). However modern web servers and browsers are able to use the same [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_Suite) connection with [HTTP keep-alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection).

Comment: It's also worth noting that these multiple requests may reuse the same connection.

Comment: @Josh: I was just adding it :)

Answer (score 0):

It's one request per asset, but you can use multiple TCP connections to send multiple HTTP requests in parallel. In fact all browser do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend downloading Firebug for Firefox, then watching its 'Net' tab while you browser some sites.  It would answer this question and so many more.